# Quick sort algorithm doesn't work

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, indexoutofboundsexception

I tried implementing this quick sort algorithm but even though it compiles properly, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
public class MyQuickSort {
  private int array[];
  private int length;

  public void sort(int[] inputArr) {
    if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0)
      return;

    this.array = inputArr;
    length = inputArr.length;
    quickSort(0, length-1);
  }

  private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
    int i = lowerIndex;
    int j = higherIndex;

    int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
    while (i<=j) {
      while (array[i] < pivot) {
        i++;
      }
      while (array[j] > pivot) {
        j--;
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        exchangeNumbers(i, j);
        i++;
        j++;
      }
    }

    if (lowerIndex < j)
      quickSort(lowerIndex,j);
    if (j <higherIndex)
      quickSort(i, higherIndex);
  }

  private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }

  public static void main(String a[]) {
    MyQuickSort sorter = new MyQuickSort();
    int[] input = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    sorter.sort(input);
    for(int i:input)
      System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at MyQuickSort.quickSort(MyQuickSort.java:23)
    at MyQuickSort.sort(MyQuickSort.java:11)
    at MyQuickSort.main(MyQuickSort.java:48)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program to figure out what index you're trying to access at that line?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `j` is getting out of range here.

```
if (i <= j) {
    exchangeNumbers(i, j);
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After:

```
int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
```

`pivot` is now `6`

After:

```
 while (array[j] > pivot) {
   j--;
 }
```

`array[j]` is `1`, so this loop never executes.

Then, because `i=0` and `j=9`, `i<=j`, so the program calls `j++;`, so `j` is now 10. Then, `lowerIndex < j` (because `0<10`), so you call the function again, with `higherIndex=10`, which causes your `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace line:

```
if (j <higherIndex)
```

with:

```
if (i <higherIndex)
```